# How to make a borrow only last for the duration of a function call

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

My code mutably borrows a reference to `Application`, but does not seem to understand that the borrow should only last for the duration of the function, as it complains about a second mutable borrow. How can I say that I only want the borrow to last for the duration of the function call?

#### Code

```rust
use std::error::Error;

pub trait Plugin {
    fn initialize(&mut self, application: &mut Application) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct Application {
    plugins: Vec<Box<dyn Plugin>>,
}

impl Application {
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        for plugin in self.plugins.iter_mut() {
            plugin.initialize(self);
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
|         for plugin in self.plugins.iter_mut() {
|                       -----------------------
|                       |
|                       first mutable borrow occurs here
|                       first borrow later used here
|             plugin.initialize(self);
|                               ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. Rust is complaining because part of `self` is already being borrowed by the return of `iter_mut`, which lives for as long as the for loop. You can't hand out another `&mut self` until the return of `iter_mut` is dropped.

Comment: Thought experiment: `plugin.initialize()` does `arg.plugins.clear()`. What happens to `plugin` in your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but does not seem to understand that the borrow should only last for the duration of the function

But the borrow is extended because the iterator returned by `self.plugins.iter_mut()` continues to hold an exclusive borrow against `self`.  This is necessary, otherwise you could call `self.plugins.clear()` and invalidate your iterator.  `self` is considered exclusively borrowed for as long as the iterator continues to exist.

In this case, one way around the issue would be to take `self.plugins` and put it back after the loop.  Since `Vec` stores elements on the heap, this has O(1) time complexity; a pointer is just being copied around.

Note also that you forgot to handle the `Result` from `plugin.initialize()`.  Since we are taking `self.plugins`, we need to be careful to put it back when we're done; simply using the `?` operator would result in `self.plugins` being empty if an error occurs.

```
pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut r = Ok(());
    let mut plugins = std::mem::take(&mut self.plugins);

    for plugin in plugins.iter_mut() {
        r = plugin.initialize(self);
        if r.is_err() { break; }
    }

    self.plugins = plugins;

    r
}
```

If this is a pattern that comes up a lot in your code, you can encapsulate it behind a private method.  This will also simplify error handling:

```
pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    self.with_plugins(|s, plugins| {
        for plugin in plugins.iter_mut() {
            plugin.initialize(s)?;
        }
        
        Ok(())
    })
}

fn with_plugins<F, T, E>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
where F: FnOnce(&mut Self, &mut Vec<Box<dyn Plugin>>) -> Result<T, E>
{
    let mut plugins = std::mem::take(&mut self.plugins);
    let r = f(self, &mut plugins);
    self.plugins = plugins;
    r
}
```

If you wanted to be extra safe, you could even assert that `self.plugins` is empty before putting `plugins` back; if it's not, that indicates that something tried to mutate it when they shouldn't have.

```
fn with_plugins<F, T, E>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<T, E>
where F: FnOnce(&mut Self, &mut Vec<Box<dyn Plugin>>) -> Result<T, E>
{
    let mut plugins = std::mem::take(&mut self.plugins);
    let r = f(self, &mut plugins);
    assert!(self.plugins.is_empty());
    self.plugins = plugins;
    r
}
```

Comment: Will Rust be able to optimize this and remove this unnecessary copying of pointers? And is that an idiomatic Rust? I'm not a Rust dev, but it looks rather exotic...

Comment: @freakish It very well could eliminate moving the `Vec` back and forth, but even if it doesn't we're only talking about 24 bytes.  I really doubt this is the kind of thing that's going to cause a huge performance problem.  This kind of workaround is idiomatic when it's necessary, yes. It's hard to tell if it's actually necessary or if there's a better way to handle the issue without seeing what plugin initialization functions do.

Comment: @freakish Another way would be to separate out what plugins need access to during initialization into a separate struct that's also part of `Application`, and give that to `Plugin::initialize` instead of the `&mut Application`.

Comment: Some other solutions: you can split the struct; you can use `RefCell`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You cannot use a RefCell in this exact scenario (I considered that as well) because `initialize` takes `&mut Application` which would still conflict with the shared borrow of the RefCell.

Comment: @cdhowie I meant making `initialize()` take `&Application` too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah, I was trying to solve the issue without changing the API. I guess that could work too, assuming OP doesn't mind the whole structure being mutable through shared references.